# allocate large (32mb) contiguous region

Tags: linux-kernel

Is it at all possible to allocate large (i.e. 32mb) physically contiguous memory regions from kernel code at runtime (i.e. not using bootmem)? From my experiments, it seems like it's not possible to get anything more than a 4mb chunk successfully, no matter what GFP flags I use. According to the documentation I've read, GFP_NOFAIL is supposed to make the kmalloc just wait as long as is necessary to free the requested amount, but from what I can tell it just makes the request hang indefinitely if you request more than is availble - it doesn't seem to be actively trying to free memory to fulfil the request (i.e. kswapd doesn't seem to be running). Is there some way to tell the kernel to aggressively start swapping stuff out in order to free the requested allocation?

Edit: So I see from Eugene's response that it's not going to be possible to get a 32mb region from a single kmalloc.... but is there any possibility of getting it done in more of a  hackish kind of way? Like identifying the largest available contiguous region, then manually migrating/swapping away data on either side of it?

Or how about something like this:

```
1) Grab a bunch of 4mb chunks until you're out of memory.
2) Check them all to see if any of them happen to be contiguous, if so,
   combine them.
3) kfree the rest
4) goto 1)
```

Might that work, if given enough time to run?

Comment: Just of curiosity, why do you need 32Mb of physically contiguous memory?

Comment: From what I can see in the kernel sources (definition of MAX_ORDER in [mmzone.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mmzone.h) and the body of [__alloc_pages_slowpath](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L2055)), allocating more than (1 << (MAX_ORDER - 1)) pages of contiguous memory seems impossible. This is usually (1 << 10) * 4096 = 4Mb. In addition, a warning should have been output to the system log about that.

Comment: Well lots of embedded devices (like phones) have hardware (like cameras and codec chips) that need a physically contiguous memory region, since they write directly to ram, without going through the MMU. This is typically implemented using bootmem - allocating a region at boot time that is permanently reserved for them, off limits for allocation for anything else. This is extremely wasteful though on memory constrained devices.. it just really bugs me that on my phone with only 512mb physical ram, I have to have almost 100mb permanently reserved for hardware that I virtually never use.

Comment: (continued) There doesn't seem to be any theoretical reason why this should be necessary - shouldn't the kernel be able to swap and/or migrate data on demand to free up the necessary region? I realize that all that swapping/migration would take some time, but I'm willing to wait a few seconds for the camera driver to load on the rare occasions that I use it, if it'd mean freeing up an extra 100mb of ram during normal usage (the codec chip uses multiple banks of 32mb each).

Comment: Yes, I see now why this amount of contiguous memory can be desirable. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: As for how to solve the problem, I don't know, unfortunately. The way you described might work but I doubt it will be very reliable. Still, worth trying if nothing else is available.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [Contiguous Memory Allocator patches](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/7/20/45). Judgging from the [LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/396702/), these patches are exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Mircea's link is one option; if you have an IOMMU on your device you may be able to use that to present a contiguous view over a set of non-contiguous pages in memory as well.